# select from 2 tables values does not work for join

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables in my database:

```
users('user_id', 'name', 'surname', 'email')
```

and table:

```
profile('profile_id', 'country')
```

In my php script there is a search box where the user inserts name, and the search script tries to select all names from my database that are from USA. Any idea how to write the sql statement. This is what I have done, but not working.

```
$sql = " SELECT u.name,u.surname, u.email,u.user_id,p.profile_id FROM users u 
         LEFT JOIN profile p ON p.country = 'uk'
         WHERE ((u.surname LIKE '$name%' AND u.name LIKE '$surname%') OR 
         (u.surname LIKE '$surname%' AND u.name LIKE '$name%')) AND country IS NOT NULL";
```

I have used IS NOT NULL for country because some users may have not field their country in their profile page.

Comment: How about reading some MySQL manuals for `JOIN` statements?

Comment: I have tried the above sql statement but gives me everything from my database not what I want to select

Comment: If `country IS NOT NULL` is a condition, what's the point of `LEFT JOIN`. You can use `INNER JOIN` instead. BTW, your query finds people in UK not USA.

Comment: any idea how to do it with inner join?

Comment: Here's a good explanation: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html Oh, and first of all we need to know what's the relation between the two tables?

Comment: How are `users` and `profile` tables linked together. I mean what are your foreign keys? Your join looks like a `CROSS JOIN` because the `ON` clause does not specify any link or connection between the two tables. I suggest you either add a `profile_id` to `users` table, or add a `user_id` to your `profile` table.

Comment: in your above query, I found there is no relationship between user and profile table. You are trying to use Left join but joins them on a static country. How to know that which profile belongs to which user?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this will work:

```
$sql = " SELECT u.name, 
  u.surname, 
  u.email, 
  u.user_id,
  p.profile_id
FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN profile p ON p.country = 'usa'
WHERE ((u.surname LIKE '$name%' AND u.name LIKE '$surname%') OR 
    (u.surname LIKE '$surname%' AND u.name LIKE '$name%'))
```

The `INNER JOIN` gets rid of the need for the `IS NOT NULL` condition **and** the `country` is now set to look for users from the `usa` instead of the `uk`.

Based on an observation by @Sina, this query is weird from the start. How do `users` and `profile` relate? If the `profile_id` is the `user_id`, then make the join work properly - like this:

```
INNER JOIN profile p ON p.profile_id = u.user_id AND p.country = 'usa'
```

Comment: Without any relation between `users` and `profile` that JOIN operator would be `CROSS JOIN` and completely pointless. No two users would be differentiated by their countries.

Comment: @SinaIravanian, you're exactly right. Very good observation, I'm going to edit to clearly address that.

Comment: if instead of USA I use china, and I dont have users in my database from China, then displays nothing which is what I want. Fine. But if I use USA as country, and have users from USA, then displays everything from my database. All users from all countries and repeat this process for about 5-6 times. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: @user2491321, that's because of the observation made and documented at the end of the answer. You currently have a cross-join going on because you didn't really **relate** `users` and `profile`. This query won't really work until `users` and `profile` is related in some way.

Comment: @user2491321, okay. Then do what I told you at the end of the answer. Change the `INNER JOIN` to reflect that.

Comment: I did it like that, but now prints me nothing at all:

Comment: SELECT u.name, 
  u.surname, 
  u.email, 
  u.user_id,
  p.profile_id
FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN profile p ON p.profile_id = u.user_id AND p.country = 'USA'
WHERE ((u.surname LIKE '$name%' AND u.name LIKE '$surname%') OR 
    (u.surname LIKE '$surname%' AND u.name LIKE '$name%'))

Comment: @user2491321, if you're getting nothing then that means that either the `user_id` and `profile_id` fields are out of sync (i.e. not what you expect) or there is nobody from the `usa`.

Comment: probably this is my problem sync! any idea how to check this and then correct it?

Comment: @user2491321, unless you have another field in the `profile` table that you can use to map to the `user` table, no, you'll have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you all users with the profile of the country 'uk', since this is your join condition.

If user_id and profile_id are the same for the same user (e.g. The user with user_id = 4 lives in Denmark if the country for profile_id = 4 is 'dk'), then you should join on this like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users u JOIN profile p ON u.user_id = p.profile_id
WHERE ...
```

If this is not the case, then you should not necessarily use a `JOIN` but just write this as where condition, and let the cartesian product in the `FROM` clause like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users u, profile p
WHERE p.country = 'usa'
```

Think of a join as somthing that puts two tables together based on a shared property. And in the latter case, there is no shared property.